# Leave a comma when going to a new line in WebStorm (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Can I somehow set WebStorm to add a comma at the end of the line, when I am adding new fields to JSON and pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Enter</kbd> to go to new line?

```js
const a = {
  a: 5
}
```

Ctrl + Shift + Enter

↓

```js
const a = {
  a: 5,
}
```

Comment: Isn't pressing comma then enter simpler than that triple combo anyway?

Comment: @isherwood I think this is a matter of habit. I'm just used to this combination because it adds ; at the end of a line in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *complete current statement, CTRL + Shift + Enter* behaviour works for me but only if there is an other line under..

There is an issue for webstorm : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30185

Maybe it helps

Comment: If you setup the trailing comma on JavaScript code style, it works as expected :) -> https://i.imgur.com/x86ceIQ.png